# Are you aware of any client-side malware that sends lots of junk requests for .gifs?

Tags: browser, http-status-code-404, gif, malware

I am getting dozens of 404 errors on my site that are requests for gif's with apparently random names, like 4273uaqa.gif and 5pwowlag.gif.

I see that most of them are coming from one user. I assume something is happening in the background on her machine without her knowledge. I assume it's a malware thing on the client.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Would love to advise my customer that s/he has an issue. I'd also like to stop getting these 404 reports. :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post full logs of these requests? It definitely sounds like malware, but it may be attempting things that are far more sinister.